# Can I run an XCTest suite multiple times?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, xctest

Is it possible to have Xcode run your unit tests multiple times?

I had an issue in several unit tests that caused intermittent failures. Now that I *think* I've fixed it, my only option appears to mash <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> until I'm 95% confident the bug is gone.

I know other unit testing frameworks make it quite easy to run a single test, test case, or test suite multiple times. Do we have this luxury in XCTest yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode has a built-in way you can do this:

Right-click the test and select `Run <test> Repeatedly...`

[image]

That menu has a few configurations, one of them is `Stop After` where you can select `Failure` which will stop the execution if it failed during one of the repetitions.

You can also run a test class or the whole test suite repeatedly.

Comment: Xcode certainly didn't have this feature when I asked this question, but that's awesome that it does now!

Answer (score 12):

For me it works in swift

```
override func invokeTest() {
    for time in 0...15 {
        print("this test is being invoked: \(time) times")
        super.invokeTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me in Xcode 10, but now in 11 not having any luck with it.

Comment: well, i have tested it and it is working for me in xcode 11 as well

Comment: I tried with 11.3. On 11.4 beta now, will try again. I’ll try something trivial...

Comment: This is working in Xcode 14.1

Answer (score 7):

Try overriding invoke test: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496282-invoketest?language=objc

```
- (void)invokeTest
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        [super invokeTest];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It might help you to use

```
func testMultiple() {
    self.measureBlock() {
            ...
            XCTAssert(errMessage == nil, "no error expected")        
    }
}
```

This runs the code inside self.measureBlock() multiple times to measure the average time.

It is work to change the code, but you might want to know the execution time anyways.

This answer might be close enough to what you want and it is easy to do.

Comment: That's true; I could wrap every test in a call to `measureBlock`, but does anyone know how many times the block is executed in `measureBlock`?

Comment: The unit test tells you in the console when you run it. Example: measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.002, relative standard deviation: 154.282%, values: [0.011297, 0.001023, 0.000956, 0.000969, 0.000952, 0.000935, 0.000979, 0.000950, 0.000968, 0.001042],

Comment: What is bad in my answer is that the tests are not mixed randomly. If you have errors that occur from time to time, the sequence of tests might play a role.

Comment: I suppose I could just wrap each individual test in a `measureBlock` block, so they'd still run in a random order. Thanks for looking into this with me; I think this is the best we can do with XCTest.

Comment: Does this call tearDown / setup after each run, I'm assuming not.

Comment: Not while you're inside the method

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to do this via the command line. You can run a single test using the `-only-testing` argument, and avoid building using `test-without-building` i.e. (new lines added for clarity)

```
for i in {1..10}; \
  do xcodebuild \
    test-without-building \
    -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Debug \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.2,name=iPhone 8' \
    -only-testing:MyApp.Tests/TestFile/myTest;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in Xcode

Edit the Test Plan. In the Test Navigator, at the top you should see "Test Plan: MyAppName (Default)". Tap on this and select "Edit Test Plan".

In the editor, select Configurations, Configuration 1

Under Test Execution you can set Test Repetition Mode and Maximum Test Repetitions.

Run the tests from the menu Product > Test

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Xcode did not have this feature when I asked the question, but it's great to see test repetition is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for` loop:

```
func testMultiple() {
    for _ in 0...100 {
            ...
            XCTAssert(errMessage == nil, "no error expected")        
    }
}
```

Note this doesn't work within a `self.measureBlock()`. You'll get an `NSInternalConsistencyException: Cannot measure metrics while already measuring metrics`

However, you can CALL this within a `measureBlock()`:

```
func testMultiple() {
    for _ in 0...100 {
            ...
            XCTAssert(errMessage == nil, "no error expected")        
    }
}

func testPerformance() {
    self.measureBlock() {
        self.testMultiple()
    }
}
```

Xcode 8 runs the `measureBlock` code 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the `invokeTest()` override in the past (Xcode 10) with great success. But now in Xcode 11 its not working (for me at least). What I ended up doing was:

```
func test99Loop() {
    for i in 0..<LOOP_COUNT {
        if i > 0 { tearDown(); sleep(1); setUp() }
        test3NineUrls()
        do { tearDown(); sleep(1) }
        setUp()
        test6NineCombine()

        print("Finished Loop \(i)")
    }
}
```

I obviously use setup/teardown, and this is the proper way to do those multiple times (since the first and last are called by Xcode).