# How to repeat a XCTestCase method n times?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest, xctestcase

I have found this question [Can I run an XCTest suite multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195465/can-i-run-an-xctest-suite-multiple-times)
Which basically ask how to run XCTestCase **suite** multiple times. However, I would like to run only one method multiple times. How can I run for instance

```swift
final class MyTests: XCTestCase {
  var subject: Subject!

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    self.subject = Subject()
  }

  func testSujectDoesStuff() async {
      subject.stuff()
  }
```

Then, I want to run `testSujectDoesStuff` 10 times and fail fast. Xcode itself allows you to do this with

[image]

However, I would like to do it programatically instead of relying on the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the test is invoked, it will also carry the `var invocation: NSInvocation?` along side with the attempt to run the test case.

So, you just have to check the right selector for the test.

```swift
override func invokeTest() {
    if invocation?.selector == #selector(self. testSujectDoesStuff) {
      (1...10).forEach { _ in
        super.invokeTest() // It will run the test case 10 times
      }
      return
    }
    super.invokeTest()
  }
```